# Center a box under a h2 title (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox : I would like to make blocks of this style under my 2 titles  ( https://prnt.sc/v91kb7 and in total with the 2 titles : https://prnt.sc/v91kp6 ) except that I have this result : https://prnt.sc/v91kf2 if someone has an idea I'm taker I dry complete here is my code : HTML : https://hastebin.com/unupukemam.xml // CSS : https://hastebin.com/acupitesis.css

```css
.movies {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;

}

.movies__title {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e67e22;
    display: inline;
}

.movies__items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.movie {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>King-Stream.fr | Streaming vf</title>
    <!-- Ajouter les meta de référencement -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/movie.css">


</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="header__texture"></div>
        <div class="header__mask">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M0 100 L 0 0 C 25 100 75 100 100 0 L 100 100" fill="#fff"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__navbar">
                <div class="header_navbar__logo">
                    <h1 class="header__navbar--logo-title">King-Stream.fr</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="header__navbar_navbar--menu">
                    <a href="" class="header__navbar--menu-link"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Accueil</a>
                    <a href="" class="header__navbar--menu-link"><i class="fas fa-film"></i> Films</a>
                    <a href="" class="header__navbar--menu-link"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i> Séries</a>
                    <a href="" class="header__navbar--menu-link"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Nouveautés</a>
                    <a href="" class="header__navbar--menu-link"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i> Support</a>
                </div>
                <div class="header__navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="header__navbar-toggle-icons"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header__slogan">
                <h1 class="h__slogan--title">Site de Streaming en VF</H1>
                    <a href="" class="h__slogan--btn">Films</a>
                    <a href="" class="h__slogan--btn">Séries</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="movies"> <!-- Films/Séries réunis -->
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="movies__title">Derniers Films</h2>
            <div class="movies__items">
                <div class="movie"> <!--  Derniers Films-->
    
                </div>
                <h2 class="movies__title">Dernières Séries</h2>
                <div class="movie"> <!--  Dernières Séries-->
    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="public/js/app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

HTML:

Comment: can you attach code snippet here with result?

Comment: You want my html + css code ? or you just want a screenshot of the result on the site ?

Comment: html css code with the live result

Comment: That's what the hastebin links are for, and I can't post everything here:c

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand normally, it's good

Comment: I would like to make blocks of this style under my 2 titles ( https://prnt.sc/v91kb7 and in total with the 2 titles : https://prnt.sc/v91kp6 ) except that I have this result : https://prnt.sc/v91kf2

Comment: I just know that each block contains a film: 160x40 x 10 = 10 blocks of size 160x40 for each of the blocks so I have the site in front of me so I have some information but I really had a hard time creating the different blocks

Comment: Oops I said something stupid it's in 160x240 px

Comment: You should include enough code in the question itself to be able to replicate the issue. Preferably as a [mcve]. Don't rely on 3rd party sites, e.g. hasebin is blocked by our corporate firewall. Don't paste everything, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What I did in my post doesn't fit in snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<h2 class="movies__title">Derniers Films</h2>
<div class="movies__items">
    <div class="movie"> <!--  Derniers Films-->

    </div>
</div>

<h2 class="movies__title">Dernières Séries</h2>
<div class="movies__items">
    <div class="movie"> <!--  Dernières Séries-->

    </div>
</div>
```

try to wrap the 2 movie class inside movies_items.

Comment: I did not understand everything sorry my English is approximate this to say wrap ?

Comment: I mean put `movie` class inside `movies_items` as the code above